# Framework Assemblies with Implementation

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, .net-reflector

Reflector displays empty implementation of the WP7 Assembles.

AFAIK the reason - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\" folder contains assemblies without implementation, just with references.

Where're the assemblies **with** implementation so I can decompile them?

If they're not on my PC, can I extract them from a simulator, or from a developer-unlocked WP7 device?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I live outside US, it's legal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assemblies in the 'Reference Assemblies' folder are only provided for the intellisence in Visual Studio. To get the true assemblies, you would have to extract them from the emulator's image. The NKBin toolset is a frequently used tool for this operation: http://www.t-hack.com/wiki/index.php/NK.BIN_toolset

Comment: It looks to me that toolset deprecated long time ago, it's only for WinCE 3-6?

Comment: No it works also with Windows Phone 7. You can find some explanations on how to use those tools on the XDA-Developers forums. For instance: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=7190440#post7190440

Comment: It worked! I was able to successfully decompile system.windows.dll (that became GAC_System.Windows_v2_0_5_0_cneutral_1.dll in the device's GAC). Thanks a lot.